# How to run Windows apps in Ubuntu Server 14.04 wihout GUI

Tags: windows, wine, gui, vnc

I have a Windows program (an .exe) in Ubuntu Server 14.04. I can run it with VNC - tightvncserver :1 . After that I connect with the Viewer, the gui is the LXDE and there is the wine icon of the program program_name.deskop, I click it and run like charm.

How to run this program without VNC and LXDE, from the shell (cli mode)? I don't have too much experience in the linux and X11 virtual displays..

Thank you, guys!:)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can search for "program_name.desktop", it's a text file and contains the actual command being run.

But it's probably something like `wine foo.exe` (see [wine docs](https://www.winehq.org/docs/wineusr-guide/running-wine))

VNC might not be necessary. Get acquainted with [SSH](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH). Then you can just get a shell to your server and run the command.